# Recommended Scala io library

Tags: scala, io

By all accounts, Scala's `Source` is a bit of a mess - everything I've read about it mentions resources left open, mysterious bugs...

I was wondering whether that was still the case in recent versions of Scala and, if so, what are worthy alternatives?

I've mostly heard of [scala-io](https://github.com/jesseeichar/scala-io) and [scalaz-streams](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) (and, obviously standard Java IO primitives). Did I miss anything? If anyone has experience with these or other projects, what are their respective pros and cons?

I'm inclined to go for `scala-io`, since I found the author's [blog](http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr) to be a fairly high quality source of useful of information, but I'd love to know more about the alternatives and what other people use.

Comment: Another library worth taking a look at is [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm)

Comment: My rule of thumb: `Source` for one-off scripts, `java.io` for most stuff, iteratees when I care more about correctness or resource management than performance. I'm [hoping `scalaz-stream`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18112224/334519) will make it possible to replace all three with one framework (and it [looks promising](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18115189/334519)).

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to edit this question and rephrase it in a way that's acceptable to stackoverflow - I just don't see how: the problem I need help with is the lack of a standard Scala IO library, and I'm not sure how to ask about this without violating moderation guidelines. Perhaps there's a better stackexchange site for this question? I'd be happy to take it there if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo: I personally think this is a perfectly appropriate question here (and have voted to re-open). Adding more detail about your use case(s) might help?

Comment: This is a fair question, Scala beautifully abstracts these kinds of problems away from Java - but the topic of I/O (while possible using Java classes) is still waiting for it's proud day in Scala.

Comment: My guess is that I/O is at the same time too simple and too diverse for a new library to help much. I/O is about reading and writing bytes, characters and lines, and that's covered by `java.io`. Everything above that layer is application-specific. Stuff below is protocol-specifc (files, http, ...).

Answer (score 6):

[Rapture IO](http://rapture.io/) might be worth trying.

It provides some nice DSL for managing IO resources of various kinds.

Answer (score 2):

Using the package `java.nio.file` in Java standard library may also be simple enough if you don't require advance features. For example, to read the lines of a file into memory:

```
Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file_name"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asScala
```

And to write a sequence of lines into a file:

```
val strs = Seq("line1", "line2", "line3")
Files.write(Paths.get("output_file"), strs.mkString("\n").getBytes())
```

Check
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html
for more information.